# creating a stored procudure to multiply values of Dropdown list with values in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as follow : (and a there is a table with some columns include `'Ta'`,`'Em'`,`'Ma'`,`'Sa'` with several different records)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cstored] 
(
@Tar int,
@Emk int,
@Mas int,
@San int
)   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 
Namecar,
Ta*@Tar AS val1,
Em*@Emk as val2,
Ma*@Mas as val3,
Sa*@San As val4,
(Ta*@Tar)+(Em*@Emk)+(Ma*@Mas)+(San*@San) as finalresult
FROM Cdetail 
END
```

and a web page include some dropdown list as follow :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            <asp:ListItem Value="8">Emk</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="8">Tar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="8">San</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="8">Mas</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="7">Emk</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="7">Tar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="7">San</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="7">Mas</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">Emk</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">Tar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">San</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">Mas</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">Emk</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">Tar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">San</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">Mas</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
```

and following code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt;
            string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                using (var scCommand = new SqlCommand("Cstored", sqlCon))
                {
                    scCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Tar", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                    scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Emk", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
                    scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Mas", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
                    scCommand.Parameters.Add("@San", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList4.SelectedValue;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scCommand))
                    {
                        dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
```

these code works , but always with same result, because of this part

> scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Tar", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
>   DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

for instance in DP1 there are several choice with value `8` and if user select anything it will be multiplied with `'@Tar'` in stored procedure, it is same for other DP, due to it the result is same always even with different selection, but i want if user select `'Emk'` in `DP1` the value 8 only multiply with `'@Emk'`in stored procedure and if selected `'Mas'` in `DP 2` ,it multiply with `'@Mas'` .
but i don't know how can i define it in codes , your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your stored procedure as like this,

```
DECLARE @dp1 varchar (100)
DECLARE @dp2 varchar (100)
DECLARE @dp3 varchar (100)
DECLARE @dp4 varchar (100)

DECLARE @dpp1 int
DECLARE @dpp2 int
DECLARE @dpp3 int
DECLARE @dpp4 int


set @dp1 = 'Emk' >>as example
set @dp2 = 'Mas' >>as example 



if (@dp1= 'Emk')
Begin
set @dpp1= 8 
Select Emk*@dpp1 as val1 FROM Cdetail
End

if (@dp1= 'Tar')
Begin
set @dpp1= 8
Select Tar*@dpp1 as val1 FROM Cdetail
End

if (@dp1= 'San')
Begin
set @dpp1= 8 
Select San*@dpp1 as val1 FROM Cdetail
End

if (@dp1= 'Mas')
Begin
set @dpp1= 8
Select Mas*@dpp1 as val1 FROM Cdetail
End

if (@dp2= 'Emk')
Begin
set @dpp2= 7 
Select Emk*@dpp2 as val2 FROM Cdetail
End

if (@dp2= 'Tar')
Begin
set @dpp2= 7 
Select Tar*@dpp2 as val2 FROM Cdetail
End

if (@dp2= 'San')
Begin
set @dpp2= 7 
Select San*@dpp2 as val2 FROM Cdetail
End

if (@dp2= 'Mas')
Begin
set @dpp2= 7 
Select Mas*@dpp2 as val1 FROM Cdetail
End


SELECT 
Namecar,
(Mas*@dpp1)+(San*@dpp1)+(Tar*@dpp1)+(Emk*@dpp1)+(Mas*@dpp2)+(San*@dpp2)+(Tar*@dpp2)+(Emk*@dpp2)
 as finalresult
FROM Cdetail
```

be note it is an example and you need to improve it